# a power series involving powers of the factorial $ n! $

Tags: reference-request, power-series

let be a positive number 'k' positive integer then let be the power series

$$ f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^{n}}{(n!)^k} $$

- if $k=0 $ we have $ (1+x)^{-1} $
- if $k=1$ we have $ \exp(-x) $
- if $k=2$ we have the Bessel function $ J_{0} (2\sqrt{x}) $

but what happens for $ k \ge 3 $

Comment: For $k\to\infty$, $f(x)\to1-x$ :)

Comment: i suppose you assume $ 1^{\infty} =1 $ but this doesn't hold always

Comment: hem, $\lim_{k\to\infty}1^k=1$. Always.

Comment: The function seems to be alternating (forever ?), with the lobes wider and wider, higher and higher as $k$ grows. This is how it tends to $1-x$.